# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS server installation wants to use wifi instead of ethernet

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I wanted to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Server but everytime I get to the network connections it shows only wifi even tho I already plugged in an ethernet cable, it also wont show any way to set it to ethernet. I continued without a network connection but then I dont have access to internet even after trying to enable it with /etc/network/interface but ifup isnt pre-installed and when checking eth0 it wont find it.

[network connection tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB4t9.jpg)

How do I make it use ethernet?

Comment: Better question why does it not see the Ethernet connect? Are the activity lamps on the card active?

Comment: is the leds on your ethernet cable lit in both the ends of your cable?

Comment: the led on the card is blinking, my router/modem has no leds

Comment: How new is the hardware? Which Ethernet chip specifically? Some newer Ethernet chips didn't have native support  in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hardware came out 1 year ago (MSI H510I Pro WIFI) and the ethernet chip is Realtek RTL8125B. I bought it about 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it like this:

First I checked the network devices

```
lshw -C network
```

It said that my network device is *UNCLAIMED* so I searched for a driver for my network chip, found and followed this:

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/Realtek-r8125/

after reboot it finally worked as intended.